# Google Script Optimization

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet in which IDs are saved. Now occasionally I need to read these IDs and check if other values(Name) in the sheet still fits the ID. The code I have is:

```
var name = sheet.getRange(line,row).getValue();
  var id = sheet.getRange(line,10).getValue();
  if(name!== "" && id === "")
  {   
    try
    { get an ID}
```

Now from what I read I know that calling each cell value seperately takes way more time. However I am not sure how to apply getValues to have these cases fixed.
Basically the same problem in a different dress I have with the following code:

```
  var id = sheet.getRange(line,row).getValue();    
    if(id!== "" && id!="Not Found" && id!="Not Found old")
    {      
      var url = "some api url "+id+"api key";
      try
      {
        var str = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
```

So how do I use get values to check every ID I get. I guess I would have to use some sort of

```
foreach(id)
```

or a

```
for(i= 0; i <= id.range; i++)
{
use id[i] to blablabal
}
```

- But I have no idea how to implement it, any ideas?
- Is there maybe even a different, more efficient way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After calling getValues you get a double array, like `[[valueA1, valueB1], [value A2, value B2]]`. Process it in a `for` loop, which may be a double loop if all row/column combinations are involved. Keep in mind that spreadsheet uses 1-bases indexing but in JavaScript they are 0-based. Often, the top row is headers, so it's omitted from the loop below.

```
function processData() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();            // all of data. could be some part of it
  var values = range.getValues();
  for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {    // skipping with header row
    for (var j = 0; j < values[0].length; j++) {
      if (condition) {
        // do something to values[i][j];
      }
    }
  }
  range.setValues(values);    // put updated values back
}
```

If the data of interest is in, say, column D, then you can decide to fetch only that column. For example:

```
function fetchStuff() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); 
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 4, lastRow, 1);  // all of column D, note 1-based indexing
  var values = range.getValues();
  for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {    //  skipping header row
    if (condition) {
      var str = UrlFetchApp.fetch(values[i][0]).getContentText();
      // do something
    }
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that `fetch` is by far the slowest operation here, and that it is subject to [quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas). Use `Utilities.sleep(ms)` to avoid invoking services too often, and keep track of how much data you are asking the script to fetch.